# how can I make the following code better?

Tags: java

I want to make the following code better, but cannot get a good idea.
Is there any way to solve this?

I just create a Android project and use greenDAO [greendao](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/) to create tables by Class.

```
for (Field field : fields) {
    fieldName = field.getName();
    // we don't need this.
    if ("serialVersionUID".equals(fieldName)) {
        continue;
    }
    type = field.getType();
    // primary key, just auto increment.
    if ("id".equals(fieldName)) {
        entity.addIdProperty().autoincrement();
        continue;
    }
    // other fields
    /*
     * this is the problem what I want to solve.
     * I thought it's too bad to read and have a bad looking.
     */
    if (type.equals(String.class)) {
        entity.addStringProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
        entity.addIntProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Double.class)) {
        entity.addDoubleProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Float.class)) {
        entity.addFloatProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Long.class)) {
        entity.addLongProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Byte.class)) {
        entity.addByteProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Short.class)) {
        entity.addShortProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Boolean.class)) {
        entity.addBooleanProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Character.class)) {
        entity.addStringProperty(fieldName);
    }else if (type.equals(Date.class)) {
        entity.addDateProperty(fieldName);
    }
}
```

Comment: switch would be better here, and much more readable.

Comment: @RahulSharma you cannot switch on a class.

Comment: you should skip all `static` or `transient` fields.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What about type.getSimpleName() ?

Comment: switch  and use class.getSimpleName() with JDK 1.8 , but I just thought it's not that better .I want to know other ways, but not found.

Comment: change entity class to have addProperty method with different parameters and let method overloading do the rest.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Erm, I didn't say that class should be used. In terms of readability, switch would be better here. There are more than one ways of implementing it, using getSimpleName for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 solution: create a static `Map` of "adder methods" where each possible property type will be associated with corresponding lambda:

```
static final Map<Class<?>, BiConsumer<Entity, String>> ADDERS = new IdentityHashMap<>();
{{ 
    ADDERS.put(String.class,  Entity::addStringProperty);
    ADDERS.put(Integer.class, Entity::addIntegerProperty);
    //...
}}
```

then, for each `field`:

```
ADDERS.get(type).accept(entity, field.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Class` objects can be compared using `==` rather than `.equals` because there is only ever one instance per class.

It is occasionally necessary to have a sequence of nested `if` statements like this to find the right `Class` object, and this obviously very ugly (see the source code for `Arrays.deepToString` for a real example of this).

There are other solutions involving `Map`, or switching on `type.getSimpleName()`, however I would personally stick to the simple solution even if it is long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use more reflection.

```
String typeStr = type.getSimpleName();
switch(typeStr) {
    case "Integer": typeStr = "Int"; break;
    case "Character": typeStr = "String"; break;
}
Method m = enttity.getClass().getMethod("add" + typeStr + "Property", String.class);
m.invoke(entity, fieldname);
```